# This page isn’t working127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

**web.php**

```
Route::view('/','home');
Route::view('login','login');
```

**Globalmiddleware.php**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(true) return redirect('login');
    else return $next($request);
}
```

> i'm redirecting default page to login page but i got some strange result which shows login page isn't working

```
This page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

> remember i have login and home views

Comment: In `Globalmiddleware` you have written if condition with true.So it redirecting to login page 

     if(true) return redirect('login');

Comment: remove true and check proper condition in if

Comment: it is redirecting but  instead of showing html content in login.blade.php  it is showing this page is not working

Answer (score 1):

In `Globalmiddleware` you have written `if condition` with `true`.So it redirecting to login page and next it will execute again so its going to `infinite redirection`

```
 if(true) return redirect('login');
```

so better check user logged in or not

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!auth()->check){
      return redirect('login');
    }

    return $next($request);

}
```

also make sure declare middleware in `protected $routeMiddleware` in `kernal.php` and dont assign this middleware to login route

Comment: here also (!auth()->check)  returns true or false .why it is not working with true inside if statement.

Comment: true is always true.but here in this case you are not assigning middleware to login page so if it true then it redirect to login page properly

Answer (score 0):

Please check your route file to ensure that you have correctly created a new route. Verify their location and validation code.

```php
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'edit'])->name('profile.edit');
    Route::patch('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'update'])->name('profile.update');
    Route::delete('/profile', [ProfileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('profile.destroy');
});
```